# Table form spreadsheet to doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet with cells avaliable for content in: A14:E.
I have a doc template where I want to copy this table with the exact format.
In spreadsheet I nameranged A14:E - "Tabel_angajati"

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Tabel_angajati = ss.getRangeByName('Tabel_angajati').getValues();
```

//google doc

```
let copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById("template-id").makeCopy(),
        copyID = copyFile.getId(),
        copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID),
        copyBody = copyDoc.getBody(),
        copyHeader = copyDoc.getHeader()
```

//Replace text

```
const body = copyDoc.getBody()
body.replaceText("{{Tabel_angajati}}",Tabel_angajati)
```

When I run this script the table in doc it's a line of values, not a tabel.

Comment: when you extract `.getValues()` you're getting a raw array of data. Are you expecting the formatting to also exist?

Comment: Also, can you be more clear with your terms? Google Sheets does not have `table` object (while Excel does which is confusing), however Google **DOCS** does have tables. So are you are you trying to insert an actual table in docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `replacement` of `replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)` is a string type. The value retrieved by `getValues()` is a 2-dimensional array. In this case, when this 2-dimensional array is used to `replacement`, it seems that `toString()` is used. By this, `a line of values` occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
- In your script, the values are retrieved by `getValues()`. In this case, I thought that `getDisplayValues()` might be suitable.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Tabel_angajati = ss.getRangeByName('Tabel_angajati').getDisplayValues();

  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById("template-id").makeCopy(); // Please set your Document ID.
  var copyID = copyFile.getId();
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyID);

  var body = copyDoc.getBody();
  var search = "{{Tabel_angajati}}";
  var s = body.findText(search);
  while (s) {
    var e = s.getElement();
    const i = body.getChildIndex(e.getParent());
    e.removeFromParent();
    body.insertTable(i, Tabel_angajati);
    s = body.findText(search, s);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the values from the named range of `Tabel_angajati` are retrieved, and a table is put to `{{Tabel_angajati}}` as the replacement.

#### References:

- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)
- [insertTable(childIndex, cells)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-cells)
- [findText(searchPattern, from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern,-from)

Comment: You are a time saver,
Thank you!
There is also a code option to keep the style from the google spreadsheet in google doc?. Here I mean the width of the cells and the thickness of the text in the table header

Thank you again

Comment: @Dornescu Lucian Thank you for replying. About your new question of `There is also a code option to keep the style from the google spreadsheet in google doc?`, I would like to support you. But, I think that this is a new question. In this case, please post it as a new question. So, I would like to recommend resolving your question in order. So, can I ask you whether your question was resolved? Because from `You are a time saver, Thank you!`, I couldn't understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: For the "There is also a code option to keep the style from the google spreadsheet in google doc?",  I initiate a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74621675/20597789

My problem of "Table form spreadsheet to doc" question was resolved with youur help. Thank you again!

Comment: @Dornescu Lucian Thank you for replying. From `My problem of "Table form spreadsheet to doc" question was resolved with youur help.`, I understood that this question was resolved. I'm glad about it. In this case, about `I initiate a new question`, I would like to check it. And, when this question was resolved, please accept it. By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: sorry, I'm new also in stackoverflow. You are right about accepting the answer that other can use it. Now it's accepted. Thank you one more time!

Comment: @Dornescu Lucian Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.